# Upload file to virtual directory in MVC C#

Tags: c#, file-upload, virtual-directory

I need to upload and save file to virtual directory.
My code is

```
private void SaveFile(string fileCategory, long freelancerId)
{
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files[0].ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            var fileName = file.FileName;
            string virtualDir = string.Format("http://localhost:54697/Freelancers/{0}/{1}", freelancerId, fileCategory);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(dir), fileName);
            var directoryToSaveFile = Server.MapPath(virtualDir );
            if (!Directory.Exists(directoryToSaveFile))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryToSaveFile);
            }
            using (FileStream fileToSave = new FileStream(virtualDir , FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(fileToSave);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not working.
So can any one tell me how can I do this.

Comment: Define "not working." Errors? Exceptions? Nothing happens? Files in wrong places?

Comment: what seems to be the issue..? have you at the very least, set break points and stepped through the code..?

Comment: A general problem I see with this strategy is the high likelihood of duplicate file names.

Comment: Yes there is error. Any code please if you have.